# C# - Check if integer property is set

Tags: c#, properties

I'm validating some properties and I need to know if long or integer values are set by other layers.

For example, this class::

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

When I set a new instance of **Person**, the **Age** gets the value 0. But I have to validate if the **Age** were set, because the **Age** can be zero (not in this context of course).

One solution that I've thought of is to use the int as a nullable integer (**public int? Age**) and in the constructor of **Person** set the Age as null.

But I'm trying to avoid it because I would have to change too many classes just to check if **Age.HasValue** and to use it as **Age.Value**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The fact the you would have to change many classes is a weak argument as any possible solution will involve considerable change.

Comment: It sounds like you want your value types to have an additional "nullable" state.  Which, of course, is exactly what `int?` is for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Int's are by default initialized to 0; Assuming you don't want to use `int?` which would work perfectly for you. You can check against that or you can have a flag and a backing field:

```
private int _age;
public int Age 
{ 
  get { return _age; } 
  set { _age = value; _hasAge = true; } 
}

public bool HasAge { get { return _hasAge; } }
```

As suggested above you can initialize it to an invalid state:

```
private int _age = -1;
public int Age 
{ 
  get { return _age; } 
  set { _age = value; _hasAge = true; } 
}

public bool HasAge { get { return _age != -1; } }
```

Or just break down and use an `int?`

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
public bool HasAge { get { return Age.HasValue; } }
```

For backwards compatability with your code, you can back it off an `int?` without exposing it:

```
private int? _age;
public int Age
{
  get { return _age.GetValueOrDefault(-1); }
  set { _age = value; }
}

public bool HasAge { get { return _age.HasValue; } }
```

Answer (score 7):

There's *no* difference between a field (or automatically implemented property) which has been *explicitly* set to its default value, and one which has never been set.

A `Nullable<int>` is definitely the way to go here - but you'll need to consider the cleanest API to use.

For example, you might want:

```
public class Person 
{
    private int? age;

    public int Age
    {
        // Will throw if age hasn't been set
        get { return age.Value; }
        // Implicit conversion from int to int?
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public bool HasAge { get { return age.HasValue; } }
}
```

That will allow you to read `Age` directly in places which *assume* it's been set - but test for it when they want to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever pattern you use, you will have to have an "is set" query before you get the value, so...

Use a nullable field `int? age` which your get/set properties use, and query an `IsAgeSet` property:

```
public class Person  
{ 
    private int? age;

    public int Age {
        get {return age.Value;} // will fail if called and age is null, but that's your problem......
        set {age = value;}
    }
    public bool IsAgeSet {
        get {return age.HasValue;}
    }
}
```